Mounting a SMB subfolder
I would like to mount my SMB subfolders. These links seem to indicate it is possible on some OSes

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483993/mount-a-subdirectory-without-intermediate-mount
https://www.reddit.com/r/Proxmox/comments/14gnfue/comment/jp7549n/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button
https://superuser.com/questions/390813/mount-a-smb-shares-subfolder-as-a-drive-in-os-x-lion
https://forums.FreeBSD.org/threads/mounting-smbfs-more-than-one-folder-level-deep.31446/post-174604

I tried
[/]# mount --version
mount from util-linux 2.37.2 (libmount 2.37.2: selinux, smack, btrfs, verity, namespaces, assert, debug)
[/]# mount //192.168.1.100/share/subfolder subfolder
Password for root@//192.168.1.100/share/subfolder subfolder
mount error(16): Device or resource busy
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)

and also this worked, but mounted share, not subfolder
mount //192.168.1.100/share subfolder -o X-mount.subdir=subfolder

Any idea what I'm missing?

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/566963/accessing-a-directory-on-an-smb-share-without-access-to-the-parent-directory
This finally worked mount //192.168.1.100/share/subfolder subfolder -o noperm
